# Retrieve the result from the database when the radio button selected by the user

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am trying to retrieve the values stored in my database when the user selects the data from the selection list and also i am using 2 radio buttons, when 1st radio button is checked. When 1st radio button is checked , get the data from table1 and if the 2nd radio button selected get the data from table2. How can i do it?

Please somebody help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="table" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="table" value="2" />
```

PHP:

```
$tables = array(
  1 => 'table_1',
  2 => 'table_2'
);
if (!isset($_GET['table'],$tables[$_GET['table']])) {
  exit("Invalid table selected");
}
$tableName = $tables[$_GET['table']];
$query = "SELECT * FROM $tableName";
```

By using the lookup table `$tables`, the user input is effectively sanitised because it is never used directly in a query.

Answer (score 0):

to do this dynamically you will need to use ajax to load in the content, jquery is quite popular for this.

alternatively make it a 2 stage process where you select the radio button, click next then load up the next bit of info. Doing it this way is less "fancy" but its far simplier if your new to coding. Just check the value of the posted radio button, and use an if condition to specify the select table.

You will have to figure out how by googling really, its not just a few lines of code i can type here to resolve your issue. but if you need further help after researching and trying we can point you in the right direction

Comment: Yup. I have to use ajax for this. and i am trying out the same by googling it. Thanks.
I will try out to get the result, if i stuck up, will need your help. Thanks a ton.